# How to get maximum amount and all other amounts separately in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Hello I am building an auction system. where for now i will consider two tables.  Auction table and Bidding table. I want to build eloquent query so that I can get maximum amount and all other amounts separately because I will transfer maximum amount to seller and other amount to refund their users.

I don't know from where I should start.

Auction table migration

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('auctions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->Integer('productID');
            $table->Integer('price');
            $table->Integer('quantity');
            $table->dateTime('endTimeDate');
            $table->dateTime('startTimeDate');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Bidding table migration

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('biddings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->Integer('userID');
            $table->integer('auctionID');
            $table->bigInteger('amount');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I want to get maximum amount and other amounts separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the amount is just an integer, retrieve all amounts and pop the maximum out of the collection

```php
$other_amounts = \DB::table('biddings')->select('amount')->orderBy('amount')->get();
$maximum = $other_amounts->pop(); // this will get the maximum
echo $other_amounts; // Here are all the amounts except the maximum
```

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Hi, @CaddyDZ `$amounts->pop()` we didn't declare amount variable so it won't be undefined variable? No, I'm not finding an error in your code. I hear `pop()` first time so curious to know about it.

Comment: i think here by `$amounts` he means `$other_amounts` which is declared . may be he missed it